# Bash if then statement for multiple, clustered conditions

Tags: bash, if-statement, logic

I am trying to write a command to only run an R script if certain conditions are met.

The conditions are clustered as follows (this is fake data, but the question is the same):

1. If the first argument ($1) contains dog AND the second argument ($2) > 10, run the elderly.R script
2. If $1 contains cat AND $2 > 12, run the elderly.R script

I have tried 2 methods:

Method 1:

```
if [[ $1 =~ dog ]] && [ $2 -gt 10 ]] || if [[ $1 =~ cat ]] && [ $2 -gt 12 ]]; 
then 
Rscript elderly.R
fi
```

Method 2:

```
if [[ $1 =~ dog ]] && [ $2 -gt 10 ]]; 
then 
Rscript elderly.R
elif [[ $1 =~ cat ]] && [ $2 -gt 12 ]];
then
Rscript elderly.R
else
echo "parameters not in range"
fi
```

How do I subset the first 2 and second two if arguments?

Right now, Method 1 is reading it as if the first argument is dog OR cat and the age is greater than 10, run the R script. Method 2, however, do not output anything when

```
./test.sh cat 13
```

is run. (test.sh is just a placeholder for the script name)

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: one idea would be to use parens to group conditionals, eg: `if ( [[ $1 ... ]] && [ $2 ... ] ) || ( [[ $1 ... ]] && [ $2 ... ] )`

Comment: Trying that now- thank you! Do you have any idea why Method 2 didn't work? I'm not sure why the elif failed.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with a mismatch of single leading bracket (`[`) and double trailing bracket (`]]`) ... you should have single leading/trailing, or double leading/trailing, but not a mix; which one you use (single vs double) depends on shell and how/what you're testing; cutting/pasting your code (with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) should highlight syntax issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider writing short functions to help you:

```sh
old_dog () {
    [[ $1 == dog ]] && (($2 > 10))
}
old_cat () {
    [[ $1 == cat ]] && (($2 > 12))
}

if old_dog "$@" || old_cat "$@"; then
    Rscript elderly.R
else
    echo "parameters not in range"
fi
```

Or, with less duplication

```sh
old_animal () {
    case $1 in
        dog) (($2 > 10)) ;;
        cat) (($2 > 12)) ;;
        *)   false ;;
    esac
}

if old_animal "$@"; then
    Rscript elderly.R
else
    echo "parameters not in range"
fi
```

---

What you were missing: too many ifs; not enough grouping

```sh
if ([[ $1 =~ dog ]] && [ $2 -gt 10 ]) || ([[ $1 =~ cat ]] && [ $2 -gt 12 ]);
#  ^................................^    ^................................^
```